# Cannot achieve max shared memory bandwith

Tags: cuda

I am working with an RTX 2080 max-q mobile, compute capability 7.5. I am trying to understand why I cannot achieve 32bit/cycle shared memory bandwidth:

From https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-5-x

> Shared memory has 32 banks that are organized such that successive 32-bit words map to successive banks. **Each bank has a bandwidth of 32 bits per clock cycle**.

I've written this test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using T = float;
extern __shared__ T bank[];

constexpr int warps = 8;
constexpr int pitch = 32 * warps;
constexpr int size = 32;

__managed__ long long starts[pitch];
__managed__ long long stops[pitch];
__managed__ long long clocks[pitch];

__global__ void kernel()
{
    auto* local_bank = bank + threadIdx.x;
    auto* a = local_bank;
    auto* b = a + size * pitch;

    __syncwarp();
    auto start = clock64();
    __syncwarp();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        b[i * pitch] = a[i * pitch];

    __syncwarp();
    auto stop = clock64();
    __syncwarp();

    auto duration = stop - start;
    printf("%5lld %s", duration, threadIdx.x % 32 == 31 ? "\n" : ""); 
    __syncthreads();
    starts[threadIdx.x + blockDim.x *blockIdx.x] = start;
    stops[threadIdx.x + blockDim.x *blockIdx.x] = stop;
    clocks[threadIdx.x + blockDim.x *blockIdx.x] = duration;
}

int main()
{
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitStackSize, 64 * 1024);
    cudaFuncSetAttribute(kernel, cudaFuncAttributeMaxDynamicSharedMemorySize, 64*1024);
    cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(kernel, cudaFuncCachePreferShared);
    kernel<<<1, pitch, 2 * size * pitch * sizeof(T)>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();    

    auto min_clock = *std::min_element(std::begin(clocks), std::end(clocks));
    auto min_start = *std::min_element(std::begin(starts), std::end(starts));
    auto max_stop = *std::max_element(std::begin(stops), std::end(stops));
    auto avg_clock = std::accumulate(std::begin(clocks), std::end(clocks), 0) / (float)(std::end(clocks) - std::begin(clocks));
    auto avg_clock_per_access = avg_clock / (float)(warps * size * 2);
    printf("min = %lli\n", min_clock);
    printf("max = %lli\n", max_stop - min_start);
    printf("avg = %f\n", avg_clock_per_access);
}
```

It measures in clock cycles the duration of the shared memory copy for each thread and outputs the avg number of cycles taken by a shared memory access. I get 2 cycles and it should be 1 cycle. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I have tried with float4 and I got the same results. You can change the type T to float4 **and reduce size to 8 so that you don't use more than 64kb of shared memory**.

Comment: Having printf in code which is benchmarked could influence your results. Have you compiled in release mode? Are all warps starting and stopping around the same time or are they running more one after the other? Could you try to increase the number of warps from 8 to 32? Could you increase the number of operations on shared memory to keep the threads busy for longer times?

Comment: @Sebastian I've tried everything except "increase the number of operations on shared memory to keep the threads busy for longer times". If I get a loop around them, the accesses get optimized into just one iteration. I have to find a way to do what you suggested.

Comment: You could try syncwarp or syncthreads after each iteration. Have you looked at the Compute Nsight? It shows the usage of shared memory (among others) in a nice GUI.

Comment: I have and it shows no difference in timings between float and float2. Both are using half the bandwidth.

Comment: According to the Dissecting the Turing architecture paper, the maximum bandwidth of shared memory is Frequency x Number of SMs x 16 Lanes x 32 bits. So two clock cycles are needed for accessing 32 bits (see table 3.1). 'The actual bandwidth we measure on the T4 GPU is 58.83 bytes/cycle/SM', which is equivalent to 2 cycles for a full 128 bytes=32*32 bits access.

Comment: Confirmation in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363610005_Future_Scaling_of_Memory_Hierarchy_for_Tensor_Cores_and_Eliminating_Redundant_Shared_Memory_Traffic_Using_Inter-Warp_Multicasting : 'However, the SMEM bandwidth per SM has been kept the same for each generation or
even had reduced in half for the Turing generation.' So shared memory is slower in 7.5 vs. 7.0. The TU104 in the Dissecting paper is a 7.5. The Nvidia programming guide documentation you referred concentrates on the flagship of each architecture.

Comment: As mentioned in [the cross posting](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-achieve-max-shared-memory-bandwith/273109), and contrary to some previous comments made here, the average bandwidth to shared memory even on cc7.5, cc8.6, cc8.9, etc. can reach 32bits/bank/clk if 8 bytes or 16 bytes per thread are requested.  cc7.0, cc8.0, and cc9.0 can achieve 32bits/bank/clk even if only 32bits/thread are requested.

Comment: @RobertCrovella but the previous answers correspond to what I'm getting measured: a maximum of 16 bit/clk/bank throughput even with float2 and float4 with all sms running at full throttle. The only time I'm getting 32bits/clk/bank is if I have only a block per sm running. As soon as I have multiple per sm it reverts back 16bits/clk/bank.

Comment: I'm not going to argue it.  The thread I linked demonstrates getting 32bits/bank/clk, confirmed both by myself and another poster besides you.  It requires at least 2 warps and also requires for certain architectures 8 or 16 bytes per thread requested.   I'm not trying to explain any other test case than that.  Your original claim was that the bandwidth cannot be achieved.  My claim is that it can, I have indicated how, using the code you provided, and it was independently confirmed by someone else.  Good luck!

Comment: If more than one block is running per SM, they are sharing the resources. Each of two could run 'simultaneously' with half the speed between the start and stop time measurement. They also could run one after the other for this section. So the time measurement in the benchmark is flawed, as it does not control or test this.

Comment: I will update the answer with the result of Greg and Robert from the crossposting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documented in the following papers, the shared memory bandwith for Turing GPUs (CC 7.5) is half of the values for Volta (7.0) or Ampere (8.x), before considering frequency and number of SMs.

See https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07486 (Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking) and https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9893362 (Future Scaling of Memory Hierarchy for Tensor Cores and Eliminating Redundant Shared Memory Traffic Using Inter-Warp Multicasting).

With Turing (compute capability 7.5) the shared memory bandwith is 16 lanes * 32 bits / cycle / SM. So 32 bit accesses need 2 cycles. On Volta and Ampere they need 1 cycle.

Please be aware that this is per SM and not per SM partition. So computation is a lot faster than shared memory bandwidth.

A kernel with low global memory bandwidth requirements and low compute requirements, but using a lot of shared memory, could easily get limited by shared memory bandwidth instead. In this case try to distribute the computations better between threads or use registers to cache data within a thread with potentially unrolling loops to be able to access arrays in registers with an index known at compile time.

The importance of shared memory (and even more of texture accesses) for high performance has been reduced over the years and architectures by introducing and improving the L1/L2 caches and also by not increasing the shared memory bandwidth.

Shared memory still provides better control, which data is kept vs. L1 cache, better random access without the need for coalescing, as long as bank conflicts can be avoided with a clever data layout and access pattern. Also the shuffle instructions have been an improvement as they are using the shared memory routing hardware and save the need for store+load or reserving shared memory, if the only task is one-time data sharing within warps. Also the asynchronous data load instructions introduced with Ampere are a great improvement for working with shared memory.